# What is the smallest possible dimension $V_1$ intersection $V_2$ must have.

Tags: linear-algebra, gre-exam

> [image]

My answer was $A$ because the two vector spaces may be disjoint and hence intersection is $\{0\}$ whose dimension is zero by convention, but the correct answer is $C$.

Could anyone clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite, there will necessarily be more intersection due to the size of the vector space the subspaces live in.

If 6 of my dimensions are covered by one of the subspaces, the best I can do (to avoid intersection more than I have to) is fill in the remaining 4 dimensions with a maximally disjoint other subspace, leaving 2 dimensions of necessary intersection.

For an easy to visualize analogue, picture 2 planes in three space. Similar to your problem, you have 
$$
\dim(V_1)+\dim(V_2)>\dim(V)
$$
Can these subspaces intersect only at the origin?

Comment: No they can not ..... thank  u so much for your clarification.

Comment: @Intuition no problem!

Answer (score 6):

Use the formula
$$\dim(V_1\cap V_2)+\dim(V_1+V_2)=\dim(V_1)+\dim(V_2).$$
If $\dim(V_1\cap V_2)=0$ this implies $\dim(V_1+V_2)=12$, which is too big.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know the following formula?
\begin{align*}
\dim(V_1+V_2)=\dim(V_1)+\dim(V_2)-\dim(V_1\cap V_2)
\end{align*}
If yes, then
\begin{align*}
\dim(V_1\cap V_2)&=\dim(V_1)+\dim(V_2)-\dim(V_1+V_2)\\
&=6+6-\dim(V_1+V_2)\\
&\ge 12-\dim(V)\\
&=12-10\\
&=2,
\end{align*} 
where you use that $V_1+V_2$ is a subspace of $V$, hence $\dim(V_1+V_2)\le \dim(V)$.

So the dimension of $V_1\cap V_2$ is always greater than or equal to $2$, which means that the lowest possible dimension is $2$.

Note that this case can indeed occur, namely if $V_1+V_2=V$. (Can you think of an example?)

Comment: No ..... I can not remember now .....can u tell me an example?